# Count the number of elements of a vector that lie between a given range

Tags: c++

For example, I have the following elements.

`vector<int> n = {10, 20, 50, 35, 40, 48, 100};`

Then I wanted to count how many elements exist within the range of **1** to **30**. So the answer will be **2** since **10** and **20** is within the **1** to **30** range.

I can do it like;

```
vector<int> n = {10, 20, 50, 35, 40, 48, 100};

int counter=0;
for(int x:n){
   if(x>=1 && x<=30) 
     counter++;
}
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: You could use a more functional style but I dont see any problem with the way you've done it. Plain for loops are often most clear.

Comment: @Edd while it works, it feels ugly, and too many lines of code when I want to count other sets of ranges. For example 1 to 30, 31 to 40, 41 to 60, 61 to 80, 81 to 100, and soon. This means I'm gonna need to declare more counter and conditions.

Comment: Open-ended feedback is more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I also suggest [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Comment: @Distro *"too many lines of code when I want to count other sets of ranges"* -- this is why one should write a function for each task (a.k.a. "a more functional style"). If your code was in a function that took the low and high values as parameters (instead of directly using `1` and `30`) then the same function could be used for any range.

Comment: Too many answers and all of them are beautiful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  If you are looking for fewer lines of code, and you are using C++20, you can do something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> n = {10, 20, 50, 35, 40, 48, 100};
 
    int counter = std::ranges::count_if(n, [](int x){return x >= 1 && x <= 30;});
    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> But is there a better way?

A better way in terms of simplicity, maybe no as it is already simple enough. But in case you are looking for a computationally efficient solution you can use binary search on sorted input.

```cpp
int main() {
    vector<int> n = {0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 35, 40, 48, 100};
    sort(n.begin(), n.end());
    auto left = lower_bound(n.begin(), n.end(), 1);
    auto right = upper_bound(n.begin(), n.end(), 30);
    auto count = right - left; // your answer
    return count;
}
```

Comment: O(n lg n) compared to op's solution of O(n).

Comment: But if the OP is looking to do multiple buckets as suggested in his comment, then this solution is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

In case your input data is unsorted your solution is correct, you can however rewrite it using the more explicit `std::count_if`:

```
int result = std::count_if(n.begin(), n.end(), [](int x) { return x>=1 && x<=30; });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in functional style for C++ 20

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

auto is_in_range(int min, int max) {
    return [min, max](int x) { return x >= min && x <= max; };
}

auto in_range(std::vector<int> v, int min, int max) {
    return std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_in_range(min, max));
}

int main() {
    auto int_vec = std::vector<int>{10, 20, 50, 35, 40, 48, 100};

    std::cout << "count:" << in_range(int_vec, 10, 20) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count:" << in_range({1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count:" << in_range({6, 9}, 0, 1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
count:2
count:3
count:0
```

you can just run it [here](https://cpp.sh/?source=%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aauto+is_in_range(int+min%2C+int+max)+%7B%0D%0A++++return+%5Bmin%2C+max%5D(int+x)+%7B+return+x+%3E%3D+min+%26%26+x+%3C%3D+max%3B+%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aauto+in_range(std%3A%3Avector%3Cint%3E+v%2C+int+min%2C+int+max)+%7B%0D%0A++++return+std%3A%3Acount_if(v.begin()%2C+v.end()%2C+is_in_range(min%2C+max))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main()+%7B%0D%0A++++auto+int_vec+%3D+std%3A%3Avector%3Cint%3E%7B10%2C+20%2C+50%2C+35%2C+40%2C+48%2C+100%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22count%3A%22+%3C%3C+in_range(int_vec%2C+10%2C+20)+%3C%3C+std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22count%3A%22+%3C%3C+in_range(%7B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%7D%2C+2%2C+4)+%3C%3C+std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22count%3A%22+%3C%3C+in_range(%7B6%2C+9%7D%2C+0%2C+1)+%3C%3C+std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++++return+0%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `functor` to build a generic solution wherein you don't have to hard code the range.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct RangeChecker
{
    RangeChecker(int min, int max)
    : min_{min}
    , max_{max}
    {}  

    bool operator()(int value)
    {
        return value >= min_ && value <= max_;
    }
private:
int min_;
int max_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> n = {10, 20, 50, 35, 40, 48, 100};

    int count = std::ranges::count_if(n, RangeChecker(1, 30));
    std::cout << "count = " << count << std::endl;

    int count2 = std::ranges::count_if(n, RangeChecker(1, 50));
    std::cout << "count2 = " << count2 << std::endl;

    int count3 = std::ranges::count_if(n, RangeChecker(51, 100));
    std::cout << "count3 = " << count3 << std::endl;
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
count = 2
count2 = 6
count3 = 1
```